# Portlet:actionurl is not going to @Actionmapping in controller

Tags: spring, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using Liferay portal-6 with `Spring-3`.

In my portlet, first it goes to the `@Rendermapping` without params and displays the default jsp,
when I click on a button I am passing the `actionurl`, but its not going to the corresponding `@Actionmapping`.

My `searchForm.jsp` looks like this:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="showSearchResultsUrl">
    <portlet:param name="myaction" value="searchResults" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<form:form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" commandName="patientStoryForm"    method="POST" action="${showSearchResultsUrl}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="button" name="search_btn" value="Search"/></td>
</form:form>
```

My controller is like this:

```
@Controller(value = "searchPatientStoryController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
@SessionAttributes(types = PatientStoryForm.class)
public class SearchPatientStoryController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String showSearchForm(RenderResponse response, Model model) {
        return "searchForm";
    }

    @RenderMapping(params = "myaction=searchResultsForm")
    public String showSearchResultsForm(RenderResponse response, Model model) {
        return "searchResultsForm";
    }

    @ActionMapping(params = "myaction=searchResults")
    public void searchResults(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "patientStoryForm") PatientStoryForm patientStoryForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult, ActionResponse response, ActionRequest request,
        SessionStatus sessionStatus, Model model) {

        response.setRenderParameter("myaction", "searchResultsForm");
    }
}
```

When I click on button in `searchForm.jsp` it is supposed to go to `@Actionmapping` but it is not going.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I see how how have you created your actionURL in the jsp?

Comment: Thanks Sandeep for ur response...here is my actionurl:<portlet:actionURL var="showSearchResultsUrl">
 <portlet:param name="myaction" value="searchResults" />
</portlet:actionURL>

Comment: Have you tried putting log statements in the `searchResults` method? Just to be sure that it is not going to the method.

Comment: exactly same problem with liferay 6.2 ee sp11. This works well with liferay 6.2 ce ga4. I think that some bug has been resolved, but I don't know which is.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to **submit the form in order to invoke the associated action method**.

However, in the jsp code, I see the below code which indicates that it is just a button.

```
<input type="button" name="search_btn" value="Search"/>
```

In order to submit the form, you can do either of the following ways:

1. Use a submit button instead of a normal form button like this:

   `<input type="submit" name="search_btn" value="Search"/>`
2. Invoke a javascript function on click event of the button and submit the form:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(form){
        var actionUrl = '<portlet:actionURL var="showSearchResultsUrl"><portlet:param name="myaction" value="searchResults"/></portlet:actionURL>';
        form.action = actionUrl;
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

and

`<input type="button" name="search_btn" value="Search" onclick="javascript:submitForm(this.form)"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your actionURL like the following

```
<portlet:actionURL name="searchResults" var="showSearchResultsUrl"> 
        <portlet:param name="myaction" value="searchResults" /> 
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Comment: The url was hidden in the question itself due to improper formatting. so I guess this answer won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the action of your form, something like this:

```
<form:form action="<%=showSearchResultsUrl%>" id="searchForm" name="searchForm" commandName="patientStoryForm"    method="POST" action="${showSearchResultsUrl}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="button" name="search_btn" value="Search"/></td>
```

This way your action name will be "myaction" with the value "searchResults" as your mapping on the controller side.